# Selenium to check if element has been visible for x amount of seconds

Tags: python, selenium, chromium

I can't share the code I'm working on because of privacy issues, but what I need it's fairly simple and my code shouldn't be required.

I have the XPath of an element. I want to check how many seconds that element has been visible, but I have no idea how.

A pseudocode example of this would be:

```
while True:
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//@[id=element]').HasBeenVisibleFor(20):
        break
    else:
        doStuff()
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the explicit wait for visibility and invisibility of the element and get the duration between them.

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//@[id=element]')))
t1 = time.time()

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//@[id=element]')))
t2 = time.time()

print(t2-t1)
```

To use the explicit waits you need to import the following

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you add a element.isDisplayed in a poll method that checks every second for X seconds

```
counter=0

while element.is_displayed():
  counter++
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Could you please share an example of this? I'm not familiar with the poll method